# Auto Advance in Qualtrics after TotalDuration reaches a certain number?

Tags: javascript, timing, qualtrics

My goal is to give participants X amount of time to answer as many questions as they can in Qualtrics. After X amount of time, I want the page to auto advance.

Participants may work at different rates of time so no matter what question they are on in the flow, I want it to advance to the end of the survey.

I'm tracking TotalDuration and I know the exact second I want the survey to auto advance but you can't feed an embedded value into the auto advance GUI. I have seen the code to make it auto advance after you answer a question but I can't find any timing related code.

Here is the code to advance after a single question:

```
var that = this;

   this.questionclick = function(event,element){

if (element.type == 'radio')  {

   that.clickNextButton();

   }

}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Use the JavaScript function setTimeout. Give it a try, then update your post with your code if you run into issues.

Comment: It may be helpful to know that you can use piped text in javascript within qualtrics, for example: var startDuration = parseInt("${e://Field/Q_TotalDuration}"); sets a variable called startDuration to the current value of Q_TotalDuration embedded data variable when the page loads.